# How to redirect a domain to a web page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress website => www.mywebsite.com
where I can create pages such as : www.mywebsite.com/page-hello.html

I also have a domain : hello.com

I would like to redirect the website hello.com to the page www.mywebsite.com/page-hello.html while keeping hello.com in the URL.

Basically hello.com stays in the UTL but users will see this page > www.mywebsite.com/page-hello.html

Comment: What it sounds like you want to do is [Forwarding with Masking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_XK7r_vlmE)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've come across such scenario where the page being viewed will be different from the URL. If you have, please let me know.

There are two ways you can redirect the *hello.com* to the page *www.mywebsite.com/page-hello.html*. 
1. Depending on your hosting company, but I think it is common for *all* hosting companies to have the domain redirection function. Log in to your control panel, under the domains section, you should find a link to add domain redirects. [See attached image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdi38.png)

2. You can do this through your `.htaccess` file. Locate this in your root folder (public_html), and then add the code below:

```html
# .htaccess
RewriteEngine on

# Require www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hello.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/page-hello.html/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that's a 301, but the URL won't be the right one.
I think the only way is with a frame. : /

Comment: That's also another option. Have you tried Forward with Masking as suggested by @Antarr Byrd??